# Evince: Unable to open external link: Failed to execute child process "env" (Permission denied)

Tags: evince

The title is the error I'm getting trying to open an external link in Evince. My default browser is the snap version of Opera 54.0.2952.71 on Ubuntu 18.04.1. I can open the external links if Firefox is set as the default browser but I'd like to keep Opera as the default for now. I was reading other questions similar to this situation and have tried updating the AppArmor for Evince to include the executable for the snap Opera browser. In `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers` I added under the line `/usr/bin/opera Cx -> sanitized_helper,` to go to try and add the snap `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/Opera Cx -> sanitized_helper,`. After this I still can't get external links opened and get the same error. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: I have the same error in Ubuntu 18.04 when I set Chromium as a default browser and try to open a link via the Document viewer.